# Nominative or accusative case for “ein Monat später”

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, time

If I want to say "a month later I came back home", should I say

> (a) Ein Monat später bin ich nach Hause zurückgekommen

or

> (b) Einen Monat später ...

or other possibilities?

Comment: Note that when pronounced usually the second syllable is  swallowed so that `einen` melts down to `ein`. So you *can, but don't need* to pronounce it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'd be

> Einen Monat später bin ich nach Hause zurückgekommen

because expressions that denote a length of or point in time use the accusative

Ex

> Es hat den ganzen Tag geregnet.
>
> Ich sah ihn letzten Donnerstag.
>
> Ich war einen Monat in China.